# selecting mysql rows for a special circumstance

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to select a new row from mysql database whenever I call a php script? For example, I need to fetch a new email address from a mysql database everytime I call the following php script. I am aware of mysqls' `ORDER BY RAND ()` function; here I need to fetch every row according to their date of entry (i.e. `ORDER BY created_on DESC`).

```
// Add recepients from a datasoutce iteratively
$emails = mysql_query('SELECT email from recepients ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1') or die;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($emails))
{
    message->addTo($row['email']);
}
```

EDIT: I will use cron job (scheduled task in windows) to run my php script, where I need a solution to select rows one by one (not randomly) as my php is called.

Comment: are you asking how to run this php script when a new email is entered? the question isn't very clear

Comment: why not you can add one more field to maintain whether the record is access or not?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. It gets all the rows. Not just a single row as your description says.

Comment: @nightgaunt he has LIMIT 1 in the mysql query

Comment: May be you can store the offset in session and increment it every time you call the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

Add column to table, if you are allowed to:

```
alter table recepients add column uts_sent BIGINT NOT NULL;
```

Update the table after sending the email:

```
$limit= 1; //fetch $limit rows per page

$now = mktime(); //current unix time stamp

// Add recepients from a datasource iteratively
$emails = mysql_query("SELECT email from recepients WHERE uts_sent<$now ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT $limit") or die;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($emails))
{
    $message->addTo($row['email']);
    $message->send();
    $email_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($row['email']);
    mysql_query("update recepients set uts_sent = $now where email ='$email_escaped'") or die;
}
```

Comment: i thing the user didnt ask for adding offset

Comment: In fact he didn't specify how exactly the thing he needs works. if he wants do do what is basically paging with page size = `$limit` = 1, then he needs to pass an offset to the script when he somehow links to the next page on the HTML-page he is outputting, either in a `<a href>` or a `<meta refresh>`.